# SSRS combining values from multiple rows (lookupset?)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm trying to display the programs a contact is attached to. When the contact is attached to multiple programs, I can only display it by having multiple rows, but I'd like to have it in one.

Currently my data looks like this (it's currently grouped by User ID):
[image]

However, I'd like to group the data like so:
[image]

I've tried a couple things, the most promising being lookupset - 
My code looked like this, but it just throws an "#Error" when I run the report:

```
=JOIN(LookupSet(Fields!UserID,Fields!UserID,Fields!PMT_ABB_Name,"DataSet1"), ", ")
```

Any advice?

Comment: have you tried using the expression without the join: LookupSet(Fields!UserID,Fields!UserID,Fields!PMT_ABB_Name,"DataSet1")

Comment: Have you tried grouping by `UserID, Name and Email`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to group on `UserId` - assuming it's unique.

Then in your `Program` text box, use the expression:

```
=JOIN(Fields!Program.value,", ")
```